# Accept Hosted - Using customer profiles to populate credit card

Tags: authorize.net, accept.js

I am using Authorize.net's Accept.js hosted solution to process credit card payments. Right now I can process one time payments but I would like to have the ability to prepopulate the credit card form for returning customers. Right now I have working customer profiles but I cannot figure out how to link the customer profile to the accept hosted form. Is there a way I can use the Authorize.net generated user ID to prepopulate the Accept.js hosted form?

Comment: I believe you'd submit customer data to the [Customer Profile](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer_profiles.html) system, which returns the ID for the created profile or the ID for an existing profile (if the submitted data matches one). Then you'd query ANET to fetch that Customer Profile's data. You'd end up charging a Payment Profile associated with the Customer Profile. See [Unclear basic workflow documentation - Accept.js](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Unclear-basic-workflow-documentation-Accept-js/td-p/57304).